# Depth first search to Solve puzzle

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list, depth-first-search

Suppose the code `puzzle.extensions(self)` has already been defined, and it will return a list that puzzle's available solutions but without the determination if it is solved. Also `puzzle.is_solved(self)` has been defined and it will determine whether this solution is solved. Here is the code that I need to write, I also do some incorrect works.

```
def depth_first_solve(puzzle):
    """
    Return a path from PuzzleNode(puzzle) to a PuzzleNode containing
    a solution, with each child containing an extension of the puzzle
    in its parent.  Return None if this is not possible.

    @type puzzle: Puzzle
    @rtype: PuzzleNode
    """
    stack = [puzzle]
    while stack:
        k = stack.pop()
        for puzzle1 in puzzle.extensions():
            if not puzzle1.is_solved():
                stack+=[k,puzzle1]
            if puzzle1.is_solved():
                p = stack.pop()
                end_node = PuzzleNode(k,None, p)
                k = stack.pop()
                last_node = PuzzleNode(p,end_node,k)
                while stack:
                    k = p
                    p = stack.pop()
                    cur_node = PuzzleNode(k, last_node, p)
                    last_node = cur_node
                return cur_node

def __init__(self, puzzle=None, children=None, parent=None):
    """
    Create a new puzzle node self with configuration puzzle.

    @type self: PuzzleNode
    @type puzzle: Puzzle | None
    @type children: list[PuzzleNode]
    @type parent: PuzzleNode | None
    @rtype: None
    """
    self.puzzle, self.parent = puzzle, parent
    if children is None:
        self.children = []
    else:
        self.children = children[:]
```

Well, I run these module in puzzle, and it always waiting for results and nothing happens, so could anyone tell me that where I got it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are a very large number of issues with this code. To start with, you're always iterating on `puzzle.extensions()`, rather than on the `extensions` of the `k` node you've just popped off the stack. I suspect this is why you're getting an infinite loop, since the same nodes keep getting pushed onto the stack over and over (and ignored by the rest of the code).

I'm not really sure why you're adding `k` back to the stack though with `stack+=[k,puzzle1]`. I'm pretty sure you just want `stack.append(puzzle1)` there, unless you're trying something really subtle that I don't understand.